Scipy filter coefficients and filtering in MATLAB
I generated filter coefficients with scipy's signal.butter to use in real time filtering in Arduino, and I'm validating the filter with a simple Matlab code that produces a dummy wave and produces a filtered wave from it.
I validated the scipy generated coefficients for a 1st order filter, but when doing 4th order the filter seems to become unstable, which makes no sense. I think it's a logic issue either on the math side, or the interpreting the coefficients side, but maybe it's a code issue.
Scipy generates 9 denominators (a0 to a8) and 5 numerators (I'm assuuming b0 to b4) but the matrix for b has the following format: [ 4.82121714e-13  0.00000000e+00 -1.92848686e-12  0.00000000e+00
2.89273028e-12  0.00000000e+00 -1.92848686e-12  0.00000000e+00
4.82121714e-13]
In the first order validation I simply ignored the 0s, and assumed the third value to be b1, so I've been doing the same, assuming the non-0 values to be b0-b4. When running the code for 1st order the signal gets filtered (commented part of the code), but when doing it for 4th order it explodes (uncommented part of the code).
Matlab code
% --------- Data Señal de entrada
Fs = 20000;                 % frecuencia de muestreo (o cuantas muestras por segundo) (Hz)
T = 1/Fs;                   % periodo de muestreo (o delta t por muestreo) (s)
L = Fs;                     % Longitud de señal, L=Fs para ser 1 segundo
t = (0:L-1).*1/Fs;              % vector de tiempo (s)
f = 10;                     % frecuencia señal de entrada (Hz)
x = sin(2.*pi.*f.*t) + 0.1*sin(2*pi*1000*t) + 0.1*sin(2*pi*5000*t);     % señal de entrada con ruido

% -------- cutoff frecuencias, wc = 1/RC = 1/tao; wc = 2*pi*fc = 1/tao
fcLPF = 13;
fcHPF = f^2/fcLPF;
tao1 = 1/(2*pi*fcHPF);
tao2 = 1/(2*pi*fcLPF);

% -------- coeficientes, Band-pass 4to° orden
a0 = 1;

% a1 = -1.99832407;
% a2 = 0.99833393;

a1 = -7.99560326;
a2 = 27.96927189;
a3 = -55.90796275;
a4 = 69.84684949;
a5 = -55.84709416;
a6 = 27.90840316;
a7 = -7.96951656;
a8 = 0.99565219;

% b0 = 0.00083304;
% b1 = -0.00083304;

b0 = 4.82121714/10000000000000;
b1 = -1.92848686/1000000000000;
b2 = 2.89273028/1000000000000;
b3 = -1.92848686/1000000000000;
b4 = 4.82121714/10000000000000;



% ------- Algoritmo filtro Band-pass
y = zeros(1,length(t));

for n=9:length(t)
y(n) = - a1/a0*y(n-1) - a2/a0*y(n-2) - a3/a0*y(n-3) - a4/a0*y(n-4) - a5/a0*y(n-5) - a6/a0*y(n-6) - a7/a0*y(n-7) - a8/a0*y(n-8) + b0/a0*x(n) + b1/a0*x(n-1) + b2/a0*x(n-2) + b3/a0*x(n-3) + b4/a0*x(n-4);

% for n=3:length(t)
% y(n) = - a1/a0*y(n-1) - a2/a0*y(n-2) + b0/a0*x(n) + b1/a0*x(n-1);

end

% ------- figuras
figure;
hold on
plot(t,x,"k")
plot(t,y,"r","LineWidth",2)
ylabel("Amplitud de Señales")
xlabel("Tiempo [seg]")
legend("Señal Original","Señal Filtrada")
box on
hold off

I don't think it's an issue, but here's the python code I used, I'm running it on collab
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal

bt,at= sp.signal.butter(4,[7.692307692307693,13],'bandpass',fs=20000)
b1,a1= sp.signal.butter(1,[7.692307692307693,13],'bandpass',fs=20000)


I see two issues with this approach, 1) I assume you are printing your coefficients into the console and copying them into matlab. The issue with this is that for visualization the values maybe truncated which can lead to stability problems especially for higher order IIR filters. Rather save the coeffs in python and load them in Matlab. 2) Excluding the zeros and changing the indexes of the nominator coefficients will change the filter characteristics, compare it using matlabs fvtool. Minor comments, for higher order IIR filters it is recommended to use SOS structures for stability.

@Irreducible Hello, thank you very much for the comment. How would you load them directly onto matlab? I tried using thos SOS structure but it's just the same array?
I'll check out the fvtool, thank you very much again.

I tried it out, it seems the 0 coefficients as you said are the actual numerators, such that the numbered values are b0, b2, b4, b6 and b8, while b1, b3, b5 and b7 are 0. the filter response for 4th order is very wierd, and it supposedly attenuates to -360 db, but the graphic response says otherwise, I think I'll stick to 1st or second order, thank you again. Maybe I'm misunderstanding again, but that's what testing's for.

Regarding SOS, no it is not just the same array, the function butter has a input parameter called output which can be set to sos.

There is nothing pertaining to the Z-transform in this post.

Digital filter coefficients are the z transform of the analog analog filter transfer function, am I wrong?, I wanted the individual coefficients to implement them in an iterative arduino script that allows for real time filtering with little operations.  Part of the issue was how I would apply the coefficients properly, specially since every other coefficient was 0 on the numerator side, I'd need the previous 8th , 6th, 4th and 2nd raw values. Or if it should be the previous 4th, 3rd 2nd and 1st. Or maybe the expression "Z-transform" is used for different topics here?

@Irreducible is correct. You have created filter coefficients that expose a numerical stability issue in the case of a 4th order Butterworth filter. See here for an explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_filter#Direct_form_II
Basically, DFII is a highly optimized implementation of a time domain convolution, but since the poles are calculated first, the gain can go extremely high, extremely fast and lead to numerical instability, especially in the case of high Q filters (which yours is an example of).
Also, not sure why you see only 5 values for your bs, but scipy.signal.butter always returns the same number of coefficients for b and a.
As suggested, express the filter as second order sections and your filter will be fine:
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal
fs=20000
bt,at= signal.butter(4,[7.692307692307693,13],'bandpass',fs=fs)
b1,a1= signal.butter(1,[7.692307692307693,13],'bandpass',fs=fs)

t = np.linspace(0, 1, fs, endpoint=False)
freq = 10
sqr_wave = signal.square(2 * np.pi * 10 * t)
plt.plot(t, sqr_wave,label='orig')
sqr_wave_1st_order = signal.lfilter(b1, a1, sqr_wave)
plt.plot(t, sqr_wave_1st_order,label='1st order')
sqr_wave_4th_order = signal.lfilter(bt, at, sqr_wave)
plt.plot(t, sqr_wave_4th_order,label='4th order ba')
sos_4th_order = signal.butter(4,[7.692307692307693,13],'bandpass',fs=fs,output='sos')
sqr_wave_sos = signal.sosfilt(sos_4th_order, sqr_wave)
plt.plot(t, sqr_wave_sos,label='4th order sos')
plt.ylim(-2, 2)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
print(bt)
print(at)

Output:
[ 4.82121714e-13  0.00000000e+00 -1.92848686e-12  0.00000000e+00
  2.89273028e-12  0.00000000e+00 -1.92848686e-12  0.00000000e+00
  4.82121714e-13]
[  1.          -7.99560326  27.96927189 -55.90796275  69.84684949
 -55.84709416  27.90840316  -7.96951656   0.99565219]
[ 0.00083304  0.         -0.00083304]


To implement your SOS filter, you basically take your set of biquads (output of ouptut='sos') and stack the filters back to back. Julius Smith has a succinct explanation: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/fp/Series_Second_Order_Sections.html.
